# How does checkpoint restoration process work?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to learn about the process of checkpoint restoration and so far I found only information about how the incremental checkpoint mechanism is working.
Usually, when you talk about backup procedure elsewhere, you talk about a full operation that comes first and incremental operation that comes after that represents the delta between the full and the incremental.
But here when we talk about incremental checkpoint then we don't take a full snapshot of the state, but right away start with the incremental mechanism.
So what I'm trying to understand is how does it work when we use retention and we have only a few incremental checkpoints left then how can we fill all the state data if the incremental checkpoint only represents the changes from one checkpoint to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for incremental checkpoints to work, Flink stores for every checkpoint the increments (aka shared state objects) it needs to fully restore the checkpointed state. An increment/shared state object is effectively the diff between two checkpoints. Depending on state accesses and compaction logic, in the most extreme cases this can only be the latest increment you've taken or the full history of increments.

Since Flink's keeps track which increments are still being referenced by a checkpoint, it also knows when an increment is no longer needed (no more references to it exist). If this happens, then the respective increment gets deleted.

Comment: I understand. So what would you suggest to do with the retention? Because you are saying that when no more references exist to a specific state then its get deleted. 
But, if I choose low retention then it's possible that states still exist will be deleted

Comment: The number of retained checkpoints only specifies how many checkpoints should be retained. But as long as you have a single checkpoint retained, it will hold on to all the required shared state objects/increments and Flink won't delete them.

Comment: So why do we have the option to retain more than one checkpoint? Because from what you are saying, by having single checkpoint retained it will hold all the required data.

Comment: The community added this feature because we wanted to add support for falling back to an earlier checkpoint if the latest checkpoint got corrupted for whatever reason and can no longer be used for recovery.